# How to calculate frequency in SQL

Tags: mysql

```
Creation Date   Account Number         FREQUENCY - 7
2/3/15 3:47 PM     7522461                    0
2/4/15 9:25 AM     7522461                    1
2/4/15 4:34 PM     7522461                    2
2/23/15 3:08 PM    7522461                    0
3/4/15 9:58 AM     7522461                    0
3/4/15 4:55 PM     7522461                    1
3/5/15 2:27 PM     7522461                    2
3/6/15 7:28 AM     7522461                    3
3/6/15 1:33 PM     7522461                    4
3/9/15 8:51 AM     7522461                    5
```

I need to find out how to calculate the frequency of an account # repeated within a 7 day time stamp. Eg: `2/3/15 3:47 PM` to `2/4/15 4:34 PM` falls within 7 days so the first occurrence will be `0` and the second occurrence within the same 7 days will `1` and third occurrence within the same 7 days will `2` and so on.

Comment: I can email the table if the data is not clear.

Comment: Where would you email it to?

Comment: Looks like you just need to `count` based on a condition being between two dates. Or the difference is less than 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

Use user-defined variables to keep track of the start of a 1-week interval and the counter within the week. When the Creation Date goes past 1 week from this, reset the variables.

```
SELECT CreationDate, AccountNumber,
       @frequency := IF(CreationDate > DATE_ADD(@startdate, INTERVAL 7 DAY), 0, @frequency + 1) AS Frequency,
       @startdate := IF(CreationDate > DATE_ADD(@startdate, INTERVAL 7 DAY), CreationDate, @startDate)
FROM (SELECT CreationDate, AccountNumber
      FROM YourTable
      ORDER BY CreationDate) AS x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @startdate := DATE('1900-01-01'), @frequency := 0) AS vars
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26efc/7)

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ':'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@startdate".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@startdate".
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ':'.

Comment: Those don't look like MySQL error messages. Are you sure that's the RDBMS you're using?

Answer (score 0):

If it is MSSQL, try this

```
SELECT CreationDate, AccountNumber,  
      (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM YourTable t2 
        WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, t2.CreationDate, t1.CreationDate ) < 7 AND 
                  (DATEDIFF(day, t2.CreationDate, t1.CreationDate) > 0 OR 
                       (DATEDIFF(day, t2.CreationDate, t1.CreationDate) = 0 
                         AND DATEDIFF(second, t2.CreationDate, t1.CreationDate) > 0 
                       )
                   )
               ) 
          AND t2.AccountNumber = t1.AccountNumber) 
         FROM YourTable t1 
        order by  AccountNumber, CreationDate
```

Comment: Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The datediff function requires 3 argument(s). - Error

Comment: Is it MySQL or MSSQL server?